# CakePHP 3 - Migrations - Specify Key Length for Text Column Index

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.7

I am attempting to add an index to one of my tables, but i am getting the following error

```
 1170 BLOB/TEXT column 'slug' used in key specification without a key length
```

This is the code I am using

```
 $tableFAQTopics->addIndex('slug');
```

What would the options look like to specify the key length, I am unsure of the array key to use for key length...

It should look something like this, I am unsure of what to put where the question marks are

```
$tableFAQTopics->addIndex('slug', ['??????' => 16]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the [phinx documentation](http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html)

```
$tableFAQTopics->addIndex('slug', ['limit' => 16]);
```